# How does a Horcrux work?

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux

We know from the series that a Horcrux is an object to hide a "part of your soul" so you can never die before the Horcrux is destroyed.

I would like to know how the resurrection process work. Say you have a Horcrux and then you get killed. Do you revive in the location of the Horcrux? Do you "discharge" the Horcrux to revive? So, for example, if you use a Horcrux to revive, does the Horcrux become empty so it has to be filled again?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - The questions spelled out in these two questions are entirely different, even if the title is the same. They're not dupes.

Comment: @Mithrandir Both are asking how the resurrection process works and the answer there covers it in detail. I looked at more than just the titles.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I don't understand how this question is marked as a duplicate as in the mentioned question is not the same question and also does not have an answer to neither of my questions.

Comment: @Levent This line from the answer on the dupe answers your question and is essentially a conclusion of Mith's answer here: _"The Horcrux also does not provide the creator with a new body or any way to return to life.. its existence simply prevents the creator from being able to truly die -- coming back to life is the creator's problem."_

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I do not see how this is an answer to the question. So you do not have a new body, but your soul still has a location after you die. The question is whether this location is the location of the Horcrux or where you actually died. In fact, in the best case that answer actually implies that you should revive in the location of the Horcrux since in the answer : "In general, for a person to die and their spirit to move on, it must ALL move on; the Horcrux functions by holding a portion of their soul in a safe, earthbound container", which is a different answer than Mithrandir's.

Answer (score 4):

You've got a few different questions here, so let's go through them.

> Say you have a horcrux and then you get killed. Do you revive in the location of the horcrux?

Simply put, **no**. When Voldemort cast the Killing Curse on Harry and had it rebound on him, he describes it like this:

> “I miscalculated, my friends, I admit it. My curse was deflected by the woman’s foolish sacrifice, and it rebounded upon myself. Aaah...pain beyond pain, my friends; nothing could have prepared me for it. I was ripped from my body, I was less than spirit, less than the meanest ghost...but still, I was alive. What I was, even I do not know...I, who have gone further than anybody along the path that leads to immortality. You know my goal - to conquer death. And now, I was tested, and it appeared that one or more of my experiments had worked...for I had not been killed, though the curse should have done it. Nevertheless, I was as powerless as the weakest creature alive, and without the means to help myself...for I had no body, and every spell that might have helped me required the use of a wand..."
>   <sub>Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, chapter 33: "The Death Eaters"</sub>

He doesn't get automatically revived due to the Horcrux. It kept him from death, but he wasn't fully alive either. It's not until 13 years later, when Wormtail creates the potion to return him to his body, that he returns to full being. He didn't need the Horcuxes near him during this process - in fact, the diary had been destroyed, and it didn't affect him (as he had his other Horcuxes around), and the process didn't mention Horcruxes at all.

> Do you "discharge" the horcrux to revive? So for example if you use a horcrux to revive, does the horcrux become empty so it has to be filled again?

Again, no. All of Voldemort's Horcruxes that had survived up until his revival still remained Horcruxes, and it's not like he had to transfer part of the soul back into him from one of the containers. All of his Horcruxes (minus the diary, which was destroyed) remained.

Comment: _"You've got a few different questions here, so let's go through them."_ - So VTC as Too Broad then...the answers to both questions you cover here are clearly different and not related except for the fact they are both about Horcruxes...

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - they're closely related enough that it's reasonable to include them in the same question. They're both about very similar topics, and it's acceptable to include a couple very closely related questions in the same post.

Comment: I'm not going to go over it anymore than this because I see no point but as soon as the answers start becoming different and diverging from each other, as they do here, then the questions are clearly different and not as related as previously thought and so it is too broad.